# iphone button text color changes by itself when clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, button, colors

Im trying to troubleshoot my first iphone app and Ive run into a propblem i just dont get. I have lots of buttons on a view and when you click them their text colour changes from black to blue. I assume that I could fix this by just setting the textColor property every time the button gets pushed to set it back to black but I feel like there must be something else going on.

Anyone know why my buttons are changing color by themselves?

Comment: that's odd... are you doing anything special to the buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have different title colors depending on button state. Set them using the following method of the UIButton class:

```
- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state
```

F.e.

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

where UIControlStateNormal is the default, not pressed, button state, and forState:UIControlStateHighlighted represents the pressed state. But there are more, and can be combined with binary sum, such as (UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected).

Comment: turned out i had set the property as button.titleLabel.textColor, and this doesnt work. I have no idea why. When i switched it to use the setter method it works fine